# local invertibility does not imply global invertibility

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inverse

What is an example of a smooth function with continuous derivatives, that is  locally invertible but not globally, and the reason for that is not injectivity.

My first idea was $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined by $f(x,y)=(e^{x}\cos y, e^{x}\sin y)$ everything above is satisfied except that the function is injective...

What example one can take?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is *not* injective because $f(x,y) = f(x,y+2\pi)$. Your example is correct.

Comment: Ah gosh, of course:) Thank you